# Exception handling by scheduled-tasks element of Task namespace

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks

I am using the [scheduled-tasks](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html) element of the task namespace for scheduling a job.

`<task:scheduled-tasks>
        <task:scheduled ref="BeanA" method="retrieve" cron="${cron}"/>
    </task:scheduled-tasks>`

```
public void retrieve() throws InstantiationException,IllegalAccessException,ClassNotFoundException,SQLException{}
```

The method retrieve throws certain exceptions, i don't want to handle the exception in the method itself due to some requirements, How can i ascertain that the job runs even if a particular run throws an exception?

Answer (score 0):

An exceptional condition is where something has gone wrong and you have to handle it if thrown exception is a checked exception but if you don't want to see boiler plate code in your calling method then you have some options like:

**throw them**

You can just handle later on and

- throw them all
- or throw as a super exception

**Handle under one super exception like `Exception` catch clause**

- This way you simply print message
- or re throw a new exception (may be RuntimeException) as Hibernate does.